# How to store the different value between two string?

Tags: string, diff

For example, here is the simple text:

`This is a texting sentence.`

and this is the modified one:

`This is a testing sentence.`

As you can see the `x` is replaced by `s`, how can I store this information? Of course, I can store the whole new string, but I would like to store the diff, is there any format or standard to represent the differ of string? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System) would be one standard way to store diffs of files.